# Deactivate add-ons by start IE with powershell (for automated tests)

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, automated-tests, add-on

I write a script for automated tests. I want that the IE runs without add-ons. It would be OK if set this after the start of it, but it is important that I can work with the IE. (I must can to grab it for my testing).

I want start IE with following powershell-script:

```
$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application -property @{navigate2=$testURL; visible = $true}
```

Currently I use a not so good/clean alternative. I open an empty IE and create an empty com-object ... see by oneself:

```
$a = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion -name ProgramFilesDir 
$b = $a.ProgramFilesDir + "\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" 
& $b about:blank -extoff    #start IE without extensions 

$app = new-object -com shell.application   #create empty comobject  
Start-Sleep 2  
$ie = $app.windows() | where {$_.Type -eq "HTML-Dokument" -and $_.LocationURL -match "about:blank"}  
#$app allocate to $ie
```

How can I deactivate the add-ons on this line: **$ie = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application ...** , or there are other alternatives for my purposes?

thanks

Comment: And it needs to be launched as a COM object, not from the executable? Otherwise you could run `C:\path\to\iexplore.exe -extoff`...

Comment: Now I have edit my question and hope it is unambiguous now. Can I do this, what you write? (run C:\path\to\iexplore.exe -extoff) How I must contain this in my code? (Do you know maybe a good website/book ... about this topic?)  thanks

Comment: If you just want to launch IE (not control it via COM), you could run `Start-Process "$env:ProgramFiles\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -ArgumentList -extoff`